# Segmentation fault in boost::python callback

Tags: c++, boost-python

I exposed two classes to python:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(client)
{
class_<Error>("Error")
   .def("GetErrorCode", &Error::GetErrorCode)
   .def("GetDescription", &Error::GetDescription)
   .def("__nonzero__", &Error::operator bool);

class_<Client>("Client")
   .def("Execute", &Client::Execute);
}
```

Here is declaration of Execute method:

```
void Client::Execute(boost::python::object callable)
{
    Error e;
    callable(e);
}
```

Here is my python code:

```
import client

def on_execute(error):
    print error.GetDescription()

c = client.Client()
c.Execute(on_execute)
```

This fails with Segmentation fault. Debugger says me that can't convert Error object to python. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question?

Comment: Also, in your python code, don't you mean `c.Execute(...)` rather than `e.Execute(...)`?

Comment: Yes it is c.Execute(...).

Comment: Ok. Without a C++ side stack trace, you won't get much help, though.

Comment: Any chance for a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?  I cannot reproduce the error.  Instead, it executes without failure.